# The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'. on Flutter how to solve it?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, sharedpreferences, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

This is my UI

[image]

In this, I used a date picker and in there shows "Birthday" word as an initial date, when the click selects the button then shows the dates, That works perfectly. But I wanna add shared Preferences to this When added that, after the selected word and close the app and reopened again then should show the date that is selected at the last.

EX:- When the user at the first time open the app then should show like this

[image]

and h or she select "2021/4/27" and after close app and reopening then should display

[image]

For that  I tried and I added shared preferences but when I add declared variable as initial value then shows this error.
[image]

My code

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class BirthdayScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const BirthdayScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BirthdayScreen> createState() => _BirthdayScreenState();
}

class _BirthdayScreenState extends State<BirthdayScreen> {
  // 1st dropdown button
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    dropdownValueBirthday = birthday.first;
    checkValueBirthday();
  }

  //date picker
  DateTime? selectedDate;
  DateTime now = new DateTime.now();
  void showDatePicker() {
    DateTime mindate = DateTime(now.year - 2, now.month, now.day - 29);
    DateTime maxdate = DateTime(now.year - 1, now.month, now.day);
    showCupertinoModalPopup(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext builder) {
          return Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith().size.height * 0.25,
            color: Colors.white,
            child: CupertinoDatePicker(
              mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
              initialDateTime: mindate,
              onDateTimeChanged: (value) {
                if (value != null && value != selectedDate) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedDate = value;
                  });
                }
              },
              maximumDate: maxdate,
              minimumDate: mindate,
            ),
          );
        });
  }

  String? dropdownValueBirthday;
  List<String> birthday = [
    'Birthday',
  ];

  //IF "dropdownValueMembers" is empty pass "which" word as a initial value if al ready selected then pass the shared preference value
  checkValueBirthday() {
    _getDataBirthday();
  }

  _saveDataBirthday(String dropdownValueBirthdayShared) async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    sharedPreferences.setString("dataBirthday", dropdownValueBirthdayShared);
  }

  _getDataBirthday() async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    dropdownValueBirthday =
        sharedPreferences.getString("dataBirthday") ?? birthday.first;
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Center(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, top: 100),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    const Icon(
                      Icons.brightness_1,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      size: 10,
                    ),
                    const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0),
                      child: Text("birthday",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                          )),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0),
                      child: SizedBox(
                        width: 110.0,
                        height: 25.0,
                        child: DecoratedBox(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                              selectedDate == null
                                  ? (dropdownValueBirthday ?? birthday.first)
                                  : '${selectedDate?.year}/${selectedDate?.month}/${selectedDate?.day} ',
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, top: 30.0),
                      child: SizedBox(
                        width: 88.0,
                        height: 25.0,
                        child: MaterialButton(
                          onPressed: showDatePicker,
                          shape: const StadiumBorder(),
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          child: const Text(
                            'select',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                bottom: 0.0,
              ),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 160.0,
                height: 35.0,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                      shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                        RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                          side: const BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.blueAccent,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _saveDataBirthday(dropdownValueBirthday!);
                      // _saveDataAgree(isChecked!);
                    },
                    child: const Text('next')),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How to solve this error and do shared Preference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`birthday` is a `List<String>` and `Text` Widget only accepts `String`

I believe you need to do this

```
selectedDate == null
        ? (dropdownValueBirthday ?? birthday.first)
        :'${selectedDate?.year}/${selectedDate?.month}/${selectedDate?.day} ',
```

Also you need to update the dropdownValueBirthday

```
 onDateTimeChanged: (value) {
    if (value != selectedDate) {
       setState(() {
       selectedDate = value;
       dropdownValueBirthday = '${selectedDate?.year}/${selectedDate?.month}/${selectedDate?.day} ';
         });
       }
   },
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your support, Now works with no any errors but still shared preferences not working. How to make that?

Comment: Hey @DasunDola Have you found solution?

Comment: Not yet bro. Do you know how to solve

Comment: Please update your question with your latest code, lemme check that

Comment: I updated my answer @DasunDola please check it, I tested it and its working

Comment: Manthri Thank you so much brother you did the biggest help for me . It works nice

Answer (score 1):

```
   _saveDataBirthday(dropdownValueBirthday!.toString());
```

make sure this is string

Comment: Thanks for your support when I add this no errors shows but at the UI display "type 'Future<dynamic> is not a subtype of type 'String'